# How to force Batch mode executing in any case for Batch class?

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to force in any case the Batch mode processing for **my custom** class extends `RunBaseBatch` by code. The user can't change the execution mode.

The shedule mode must only to be in **Batch**.

[image: ForceBatchMode]

I try to use in `main` method, before `promt` command
these code line:

```
className.mustGoBatch();
className.parmInBatch(true);
className.doBatch();
```

BUT **not** work, I see the flag *Batch processing* switch off.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `className.batchInfo().parmBatchExecute(NoYes::Yes);`

see `Tutorial_RunbaseBatch` class for example:

```
static void main(Args args)
{
    Tutorial_RunbaseBatch    tutorial_RunBase;
;
    tutorial_RunBase = Tutorial_RunbaseBatch::construct();

    // add this parm to switch on a batch processing
    tutorial_RunBase.batchInfo().parmBatchExecute(NoYes::Yes);

    if (tutorial_RunBase.prompt())
        tutorial_RunBase.run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mazzy, Helpful Answer, I added more informtion about solution.  I really appreciate your time.